# Google Chrome BUG: Transform property makes div get pixelated

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

I have been working in a pop up. It's centered vertically and horizontally in the main div. I have used the following code:

**CSS**

```
#pop-up {
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 420px;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

But everytime I hover the DIV, it get pixelated. I have been reading about it and it's a Google Chrome's bug. I have tried different solutions but it didn't help me out. So, can you help me to fix it?